# newlib printf function bug

Tags: c, printf, uart, newlib

I am trying to send printf data to my `uart` device.
I have suitablely written write_r() funciton.

The problems that I am having is,

- When I say `printf(" My name is sam \n I am fine ");`
- and in next time when i say `printf(" I am back ");`

**1st problem** :  I can see only *"My name is Sam"*, then the cursor goes to next line and stops there.

**2nd problem** : *"I am back"* is not getting printed at all.

I tried by removing `\n` , still the 2nd `printf` doesn't get printed.
There is nothing wrong with the `uart`.

Looks like then `\` is reached the pointer is lost.

**My Code**

```
    int write(int file, char *ptr, int len) {

            #if !defined( OUT_8 )
        #define OUT_8(p,d)      (*(volatile char *)(p) = (char)(d))
        #endif
        #if !defined( IN_8 )
            #define IN_8(p)         ((*(volatile char *)(p)))
        #endif

        OUT_8(DUART1_UMCR1, 0x02); //Informs external modem or peripheral that the UART is ready for sending data
        OUT_8(DUART1_ULCR1, 0x03);
        OUT_8(DUART1_UIER1, 0x0f);
        OUT_8(DUART1_UFCR1, 0x8f);

        OUT_8(DUART1_UTHR, '\n');
        OUT_8(DUART1_UTHR, '\r');
        while (ptr!=NULL)
        {
            if (*ptr=='\n') // JUST A TRY to avoid \n bug
            {
             OUT_8(DUART1_UTHR, '\n');
             wait();
             *ptr++;
             *ptr++;
             OUT_8(DUART1_UTHR, *ptr++); // \n & \r when given through printf isNot working
             wait();
            }


            OUT_8(DUART1_UTHR, *ptr++); // \n & \r when given through printf is not working 
            wait(); // TODO:

            if(len==0)
                break;
            else
                len--;
        }

            OUT_8(DUART1_UMCR1, 0x00); // say that modem is not not ready. Connection over
            OUT_8(DUART1_UFCR1, 0x87);
            OUT_8(DUART1_ULCR1, 0x00); // Clear all the interrupts ! virtually shut the UART port
    errno = ENOSYS;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I think, when you give printf("some text \n other text"), *ptr never gets '\n', it gets '\' and 'n' separately, as the input is a string. You need to handle that exclusively by something like:
if(*ptr=='\' && *(ptr+1)=='n')

Comment: The whole `if (*ptr=='\n') { ...} is certainly not needed.

Comment: @Dipto Yes I tried, its not working.

Comment: @chux .. No, its not working, whenever I '\' occurs, the ptr is getting lost, the value of ptr is getting from unknown/unexpected values. Its something related to Newlib.  Can you please tell where exactly this special character is programmed ?

Comment: @Sumanth In C, the backslash is written in coded as `'\\'`. The newline is written as `'\n'`. Your _code_ has 2 characters, but the string formed has only 1. The code `if(*ptr=='\n') { ...}` has nothing to do with an occurrence of a backslash in `ptr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confident that OP's I/O is buffered *somewhere*.
Output does not appear until a `\r` and/or `\n` is sent.

```
#if !defined( OUT_8 )
  #define OUT_8(p,d)      (*(volatile char *)(p) = (char)(d))
#endif

// make ptr a `const char *`
int write(int file, const char *ptr, int len) {
  OUT_8(DUART1_UMCR1, 0x02); //Informs UART is ready for sending data
  OUT_8(DUART1_ULCR1, 0x03);
  OUT_8(DUART1_UIER1, 0x0f);
  OUT_8(DUART1_UFCR1, 0x8f);

  while (len-- > 0) {
    OUT_8(DUART1_UTHR, *ptr++);
    wait();
  }

  // Force an EOL at the _end_ of transmission.
  OUT_8(DUART1_UTHR, '\n');
  OUT_8(DUART1_UTHR, '\r');
  wait();

  OUT_8(DUART1_UMCR1, 0x00); // say that modem is not not ready. Connection over
  OUT_8(DUART1_UFCR1, 0x87);
  OUT_8(DUART1_ULCR1, 0x00); // Clear all interrupts! virtually shut UART port
  errno = ENOSYS;
  return -1;
}
```

---

I suspect that the buffering is occurring in the *receiving*  side, either the UART or more likely in the *terminal* viewing the data.  OP said "the curser goes to next line".  There is no "cursor" in a UART.

Comment: Exactly, It is buffered in some code of 'vfprintf.c' of newlib. I am just not able to figure out where ?  I am sure that there is no mistake in UART. Boz the UART is pure bare metal, and its working great - tested with all kinds of characters & special characters like \n etc..

Comment: @Sumanth Try sending various messages interspersed with serial cable physical disconnections/connections.  Then you can know which side is buffering the data.

Comment: Well, I guess - I am using memory map heap1, where the memory cannot be freed -memory can only be created and not free'd. Please let me know, if this is the reason why printf is working only once, the 2nd call of print is not working. My question is does printf tries to free the memory after its used or when some special characters are used ?? @chux

Comment: @Sumanth `printf()` may be be doing some memory allocation/freeing though I doubt it.  Even if it did, the problem you have is not that issue.  I suspect the reason you do not see the 2nd line is due to the receiving end doing some buffering and not `printf()`.

Comment: I checked with step input of debugger. What I observed is write() function of newlib_stubs.c (where the driver for UART is written) is never called for 2nd printf. Yes for 1st printf it does send data to write().   I guess, I am using heap1 type of memory management system, where in MEMORY CAN ONLY BE ALLOCATED; BUT NEVER FREED. can this be the problem that after 1st printf its not able to free the memory and 2nd printf is not able to have any memory for buffer ? But newlib code is very confusing to understand.  @chux

Comment: Good observations.  Detail requested: presently, does your first `printf()` consist of " My name is sam \n I am fine " or what?  Does it _all_ get passed _exactly_ as that to `write()`?  Is your serial interface using no-handshaking, RTS/CTS or XON/XOFF? (Goal is to understand the workings of `\n` and `\r` in your system.)

Comment: Thought I'd pass on a parting thought.  If there are mysterious memory issues, maybe problem is radically elsewhere in code.  It is that the manifestation of that problem shows up when attempting the second `printf()`.

Comment: Yes my 1st printf consists "My name is sam \n I am fine", in my observation only 16 characters are passed to write(). i.e., only till '\'. and the agrument 'int len' is also 16 instead of 27. And if I remove '\n' everything is getting printed. its just somewhere where special codes are defined like \n \r etc  @chux

Comment: I firmly belive that UART is working fine because, 1st we are passing individual ch to the UART register. I tested wit this code. `OUT_8(DUART1_UTHR, '\n');
OUT_8(DUART1_UTHR, '\r');                                OUT_8(DUART1_UTHR, 's');
OUT_8(DUART1_UTHR, 'a');                             OUT_8(DUART1_UTHR, 'm');
  OUT_8(DUART1_UTHR, '-');                                          OUT_8(DUART1_UTHR, '\n');
  OUT_8(DUART1_UTHR, '\r');OUT_8(DUART1_UTHR, 'G');
  OUT_8(DUART1_UTHR, '8');`           ANd I got prefect output. like **sam-** in a new line & **G8** in fresh next line.

Comment: @Sumanth Given "My name ...", the 1st char is `'M'` and the 16th is `'\n'`, not `'\'`.  (Note: OP comment section sometime eats spaces on display.)  My earlier question and your original post, lead with a `' '`.  I'm pedantic here as a way to help determine if the 16 characters include the newline `'\n'` or not.  The above comment and OP "looks like then '\' is" _imply_ your see "\n" as 2 distinct characters.  `\n` is 2 distinctive characters in code, but they form only 1 `char`, the new-line character, in the string.

Comment: In any case, sounds like you are likely well aware of `\n`, etc.

Comment: I am very sorry for the mistake in describing. Yes it includes '\n' -as a single char. As the cursor goes to the next line, but doesn't print any thing futher. That's because, soon after '\n', the pointer (*ptr) is observed (I just discovered it) to become NULL. Hence, you can see  OUT_8(DUART1_UTHR, *ptr++); has got nothing to print. Why is that pointing to NULL ?

Comment: @Sumanth Yes! Getting closer ....  In `write()`, I do not see anything that would set your pointer to NULL, likely the issue in in other code.

Comment: There are three types of buffering in the newlib code. viz., fully buffered, partially buffered, and line buffering.  Its considering line buffer, here. I dunno why its considering line buffer. And there is some mistake in line buffer code, which is not going back to the next line buffer after every '\n' is printed. Hopefully if figure it out why its not happening or why its considering line buffer type of buffering then, I wopuld be able to solve it. If have any idea then, you can suggest me please.

Comment: @Sumanth A few long shot ideas:  Use `\r\n` instead of `\n\r`.  The first is more common.  Experiment, if able, with the different buffering modes.

Comment: @Sumanth I'm not a newlib user.  Suggest forming a new question.  Making it well crafted.  Have it reference this question, but show how additional issues remain.  Try to simplify the code and still show the problem. Maybe _not_ tag it a C as it sounds like a newlib issue.

Comment: NEXT LINE bug found  :--- it was because, previously it was returning -1;  BUt it should have been the pointer,..  I should return pointer and not -1 !!!! NOW NEXT TASK IS  to find out why 2nd printf is not working.

Comment: With proper prototypes and warnings turned on, this type of error should have shown itself in code compilation some time ago.  Are all warnings turned on and are you getting warning free compilation?

Comment: I managed to fix Both the tasks - again it was similar #&# missing. Thanks @chux. Unfortunately, yes.. it was error free compliation. cross compalining with CMake.

Comment: **THE** **PROBLEM** **IS** **SOLVED:** **SOLUTION**  the function should return 'len' and NOT '-1' **

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `fflush()` to force printing without a `\n`.